# Java FX create Custom Dialog with fxml file. How to set or get result from it?

Tags: javafx

Here, I want to create a custom dialog that works like `Alert`, with a beautiful UI; "showDialog.fxml" is a `DialogPane`.

I tried `JFXDialog` but it is not waiting and it is not giving me the users's choice. Is there any way to get a good `result`? Thanks in advance.

This is my `Alert` implementation:

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Выход");
    alert.setHeaderText("Are you really want to exit ?");
    ButtonType yes = new ButtonType("Yes");
    ButtonType no = new ButtonType("No");
    alert.getButtonTypes().clear();
    alert.getButtonTypes().addAll(yes, no);

    Optional<ButtonType> option = alert.showAndWait();
    if (option.get() == yes) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        alert.close();
        event.consume();
    }
}
```

This is the new one.

```
 primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
     FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/common/showDialog.fxml"));
     ShowDialogController controller = loader.getController();
     Dialog<JFXButton> dialog = new Dialog<>();

     DialogPane confirmationDialogView = null;
     try {
         dialog.setDialogPane(loader.load());
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     dialog.showAndWait();
}
```

And this the FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.octicons.OctIconView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<DialogPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="900.0" styleClass="main_color_green" stylesheets="@../../css/style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <graphic>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="900.0" styleClass="main_color_green" stylesheets="@../../css/style.css">
            <GridPane layoutX="161.0" layoutY="84.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </columnConstraints>

                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                </rowConstraints>

                <GridPane>
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>

                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>

                    <OctIconView fx:id="octionIconView" fill="WHITE" glyphName="ALERT" size="200" wrappingWidth="198.0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
                </GridPane>

                <GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>

                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="30.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>

                    <JFXButton fx:id="btnNo" prefHeight="94.0" prefWidth="295.0" styleClass="dialogBtn" stylesheets="@../../css/btn.css" text="НЕТ" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                        <GridPane.margin>
                            <Insets left="50.0" />
                        </GridPane.margin>
                    </JFXButton>

                    <JFXButton fx:id="btnYes" prefHeight="94.0" prefWidth="337.0" styleClass="dialogBtn" stylesheets="@../../css/btn.css" text="ДА" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                        <GridPane.margin>
                            <Insets right="50.0" />
                        </GridPane.margin>
                    </JFXButton>

                    <Label fx:id="labelInformation" alignment="CENTER" text="Label" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                        <font>
                            <Font size="24.0" />
                        </font>
                    </Label>
                </GridPane>
            </GridPane>
        </AnchorPane>
    </graphic>
</DialogPane>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dialogs in javaFX are an instance of the TEMPLATE class [Dialog<R>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html). Where R is the return type (if missing, [ButtonType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonType.html) is used by default).

For your own implementation of a dialog, you must expand Dialog and e if you want to get a different type of data from it, submit [ResultConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#setResultConverter-javafx.util.Callback-) (instance of Callback<ButtonType, R>). Another option to get the result of a dialog is to manually call [setResult](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#setResult-R-) and then [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#close--) the dialog.

When you want to use *FXML*, you usually use the structure of your dialog to load the desired [DialogPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html) from the corresponding *fxml* file.

Here is an example:

```
<DialogPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" prefWidth="500">

    <content>
        <GridPane hgap="5" vgap="5">
            <Label text="Адрес на хост:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
            <TextField fx:id="hostnameTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>

            <Label text="База данни:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
            <TextField fx:id="databaseTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

            <Label text="Потребителско име:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
            <TextField fx:id="usernameTextField" prefWidth="200" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.fillWidth="false"/>

            <Label text="Парола:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
            <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" prefWidth="200" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.fillWidth="false"/>

            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            </columnConstraints>
        </GridPane>
    </content>

    <buttonTypes>
        <ButtonType fx:id="connectButtonType" text="Свързване" buttonData="OK_DONE"/>
        <ButtonType text="Затвори" buttonData="CANCEL_CLOSE"/>
    </buttonTypes>

</DialogPane>
```

```
public class ConnectDialog extends Dialog<Connection> {

    @FXML
    private TextField hostnameTextField;

    @FXML
    private TextField databaseTextField;

    @FXML
    private TextField usernameTextField;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;

    @FXML
    private ButtonType connectButtonType;

    private ObjectProperty<Connection> connection = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);

    public ConnectDialog(Window owner) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/xelapos/gui/client/dialog/dialog_pane_connect.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);

            DialogPane dialogPane = loader.load();
            dialogPane.lookupButton(connectButtonType).addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ANY, this::onConnect);

            initOwner(owner);
            initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            setResizable(true);
            setTitle("Свързване с база данни");
            setDialogPane(dialogPane);
            setResultConverter(buttonType -> {
                if(!Objects.equals(ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE, buttonType.getButtonData())) {
                    return null;
                }

                return connection.getValue();
            });

            setOnShowing(dialogEvent -> Platform.runLater(() -> hostnameTextField.requestFocus()));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void onConnect(ActionEvent event) {
        String jdbcUrl = String.format(
                "jdbc:postgresql://%s/%s",
                hostnameTextField.textProperty().getValueSafe(),
                databaseTextField.textProperty().getValueSafe()
        );

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, usernameTextField.textProperty().getValueSafe(), passwordField.textProperty().getValueSafe());
            connection.setValue(conn);
            return;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.initOwner(getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow());
            alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            alert.setResizable(true);

            alert.setTitle(getTitle());
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText(e.getLocalizedMessage());

            alert.show();
        }

        event.consume();
    }
}
```

And of course, the use:

```
ConnectDialog dialog = new ConnectDialog(stage);
dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(conn -> {
    System.out.println("Open connection!");
    connection.setValue(conn);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [implementation of **MessageBox**](https://github.com/MartiniDry/Mazette/tree/master/src/com/rosty/maze/view/box), which extends the `Alert` class. If you want to add CSS style to beautify your window, you have to define `MessageBox.setStyleSheet` when loading your application (only once, it is not necessary to call it each time you want to display a `MessageBox`):

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        MessageBox.setStyleSheet("/your/path/.../message-box.css");

        ...

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            try {
                MessageBox dialog = new MessageBox(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, primaryStage, "Do you really want to exit?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
                dialog.setTitle("Выход");

                Optional<ButtonType> option = dialog.showAndWait();
                if (option != null && option.get() == ButtonType.YES)
                    System.exit(0);
                else {
                    dialog.close();
                    event.consume();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can check [message-box.css](https://github.com/MartiniDry/Mazette/tree/master/src/com/rosty/maze/view/css) whether you want to custom the component style.